# Condense SQL list if any value present

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like this:

```
Email | Value
a     |  T
a     |  F
b     |  T
c     |  F
c     |  F
```

I want to convert all Values for an email to T if T is present, otherwise keep as F, then group by unique email:

```
Email | Value
a     | T
b     | T
c     | F
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: Can there ever be two different values and no 'T' for an email? E.g. Email d / Value X, Email d / Value Y. Which of the values would you want to show in this case?

Comment: Only two different values, always show T over F if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With those values, you can use `max()` and `group by`.

```
select Email, max(value) as Value
from t
group by Email
```

Comment: Those are example values. The real values are longer text than that. Is there an easy way to group on those or should I convert them to values that can be "max"ed?

Comment: @NBC which database are you using? If it supports `row_number()` then you could use a variation on top 1 per group with that and your custom ordering.

Comment: @NBC . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have another question you should ask it as *another* question, not in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Gordon!

@SqlZim, I'm using Teradata, it does support that function

Comment: @NBC I'm not familiar with teradata, but if you ask a new question with more specific and relevant examples and tag it as teradata, I bet Gordon will answer it ^.^

Comment: This solution is built on the alphabetic order of `F` and `T`, If you are using other values the solution might have to be modified.